# DotNetNuke custom module doesn't load images or CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke-6

I have a localhost install of DotNetNuke 6.2.6 with a custom module.

The problem is that any images or css contained in the module.css file does not load. Firebug reports an 500 Internal Server error when retrieving the images or the module.css files.

My image tag is:

```
"< asp:Image ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/PositionsManagement/images/delete.gif" runat="server" / >"
```

The web browser displays a broken image icon whose properties point to

```
http://localhost/dotnetnuke/DesktopModules/PositionsManagement/images/delete.gif
```

When I try to navigate to the above link I get hit with the following error message:

*The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file.*

And when I remove the targetframework attribute like it suggests I get this:

*Parser Error Message: The code subdirectory '/dotnetnuke/DesktopModules/PositionsManagement/App_Code/RazorHelpers/' does not exist.*

Does anyone know what the problem is or how I get the RazorHelpers content it seems to be wanting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems DNN doesn't play nice with Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012. Whether it's Win8, or some combination of all of them, I have no idea.

I rectified the problem by creating a Windows 7 virtual Machine.

EDIT: With some local assistance, it seems that deleting the modules web.config file and cleaning up my Web APplications in the App Pool helped. (I had it in there twice somehow, at localhost/dotnetnuke/etc and localhost/dnn/etc. After cleaning up and deleting the web.config it started working again.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look in IIS Manager.
I got this error and resolved it by deleting the application created on the folder of the module in error.
I don't know why this folder was converted in application.

[image: Before deleting application]

[image: After deleting application]

Comment: Thank you. This should be probably the accepted answer.